# cut a postgres table into small tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

A big table is saved in a **postgres** database with the name **EZDATA**.

It contains 12 million rows.

I want to cut it into 20 small tables, 500000 rows each, 
(EZDATA1, EZDATA2,...)

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: For just 12 million rows this is typically unnecessary. Why do you think you need to do that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: https://blog.akquinet.de/2014/04/07/postgresql-partitioning-big-tables-part-1/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I am doing some changes on the table. As I run the query for 12 M. It took 2 days and the query didn't finish. I thought I should cut the table and process them one by one; Especially I am exporting later the changed table to sqlite database. So my thought is to do it in small parts.

Comment: In that case partitioning will work but partitioning doesn't play well with foreign keys. Are you changing the table structure or the data?

Comment: Why not ask for help to tune the query? But please read [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) then provide all the information listed there (as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please)

Comment: @e4c5: actually I am checking some existing columns, if they verify some conditions. Depending to the condition, I am changing data in other columns => So I am changing data.

Comment: In that case partitioning is unlikely to work. As @a_horse_with_no_name said, you ought to post a question asking for help with your query. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, e4c5: I didn't get, why partitioning is not helpful. At least I can get one small table processed and export it to sqlite and start work on it while processing other small table in postgresql.

Comment: can someone please help me in the partitioning query?

Comment: Again: show us the slow query that you _think_ would benefit from partitioning. I don't see why that would help you "*get one small table processed ... while processing other small table*". You are not limited to a single transaction working on one table. If all your transactions work on different "parts" of the table you can absolutely do that without partitioning. For exporting a subset, simply use a `where` clause to limit the number of rows.

Comment: If something is working slow, [edit] your question add that query  and the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create tables `EZDATA1`, `EZDATA2` with the same schema as `EZDATA` than

```
INSERT INTO EZDATA1 SELECT * FROM EZDATA ORDER BY id LIMIT 600000;
INSERT INTO EZDATA2 SELECT * FROM EZDATA ORDER BY id LIMIT 600000 OFFSET 600000;
INSERT INTO EZDATA2 SELECT * FROM EZDATA ORDER BY id LIMIT 600000 OFFSET 1200000;
...
```